# Get eslint quick fixes to work for JavaScript in HTML in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have the ESLint plugin installed in VSCode and it's linting both JavaScript in .js files and html file but in .js files there are quick fix options

[image]

But in HTML there are not

[image]

Is it possible to turn on the quick fix features for JavaScript in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens also in `.vue` files, fortunately [dbaeumer fixed it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/185). To quote him:

> The reason is that I encounter cases for non JavaScript file types where the computed fixes had wrong positions resulting in 'broken' documents. To enable it simply
>   provide an object literal in the validate setting with the properties `language` and `autoFix` instead of a simple `string`. An example is:
>
> ```json
> "eslint.validate": [
>   "javascript",
>   "javascriptreact",
>   { "language": "html", "autoFix": true }
> ]
> ```

Comment: There must be more to it since [that's not working for me](https://i.imgur.com/CICq9FD.png)

Comment: You also have to have the correct version (try to update vscode + eslint to latest) and not to have conflict with another plugin. I think you will find all the details you need in the thread I mentioned :)